# trackpoint issue, close lid without suspending

Tags: drivers, thinkpad, trackpoint

I own a thinkpad t14s gen1, ubuntu 22.
I have using gnome tweaker, I have configured the lid to not trigger suspend.
Since, I have issue with the trackpoint and phyical touchpad button. When the lid is openened, they are sometimes not working.

## what I think is happening

When I closed the lid, the screen turn off. I suspect the trackpoint also turns off, and I suspect it does not correctly turn on when the lid is openened.

Comment: What do you get for `sudo evdev` before and after the problem starts? If the lid approaches the trackpoint, perhaps it got sent out of calibration.

Answer (score 1):

answer:
this is a known bug from ELAN firmware (blame is on lenovo and ELAN)
they are supposedly working on it:
https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-Z-series-Laptops/Z13-trackpoint-stops-working-after-lid-is-closed/m-p/5166498?page=5

more info here:
https://github.com/fwupd/firmware-lenovo/issues/388

For know I re-enabled "sleep on lid close", since it seems to fix the issue.